# yad: how to set font size? Is there a bug?

Tags: x11, yad

I use yad fonts as [pango](/questions/tagged/pango) style, like the man page required:

```
yad --width=250 --text 'foo bar base' --fontname="Serif bold italic 90"
```

there's no difference if I do

```
yad --width=250 --text 'foo bar base' --fontname="Serif bold italic 10"
```

bug or [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#PEBKAC/PEBCAK/PICNIC)?

Modified example from doc page: http://smokey01.com/yad/

Better real test case, using `<span font="24">` trick (display the tag as is without HTML rendering):

```
yad --no-focus --on-top --borders=10 --geometry -0+80 --height=100 --no-markup --question --title 'title' --text '<span font="24">coucou\nhey\n20230228</span>'
```

Answer (score 2):

This [was a bug](https://github.com/v1cont/yad/issues/62), which was fixed back in February 2020.

However, that's not where your problem lies!

The `--fontname` option works only in the font selector (`--font`), print options (`--print`), and text info (`--text-info`) dialogues.

For the text part of the dialogue, you need to use `<span>`.

Example: A simple prompt with parts of the text prompt highlighted.

```
yad --text='Part of this is <span foreground="red" font="Impact" font-size="xx-large">red and big!</span>.'
```

Example: For text-info, you might have the following, where the text prompt is green, and the displayed text-info box uses Liberation Serif:

```
yad --text-info --listen --text='<span foreground="green">List of trees</span>' --fontname='Liberation Serif Regular 10'
```